# htaccess en php no funciona

Tags: php, .htaccess

Estoy implementando htaccess en mi web para que no salga el .php en la url, cosa que funciona solo en el index.

El codigo del htaccess es el siguiente:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

El problema es que no funciona en los archivos php que tengo dentro de una carpeta. El htaccess lo tengo guardado en el main de la carpeta donde tengo el index.php, y los demas archivos php los tengo guardados dentro de una carpeta.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba cambiando estas dos:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
```

por estas otras:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ $1/$2.php
```

Answer (score 0):

El index lo toma seguramente pq es el default ( carpetas y raiz busca un index.php o index.html ), al resto no te compliques mucho, si queres que `/algo/enviarform.php` pueda ser llamado onda `/enviarform` pones un `RewriteRule  ^enviarform/?$  "/algo/enviarform\.php"`  de esa manera es mapeo interno y no una redireccion.

Fijate ejemplos de https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html y una vez que tengas practica empezas a poner expresiones y comodines.

Si querés usar comodines, la forma típica es algo así:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

condición: que lo que piden no es una carpeta `(!)no (-d)irectory`

---

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

condición: que lo que piden no es un archivo `(!)no (-f)ile`

---

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
```

condición: que lo que piden si le agrego "`.php`" es un archivo `(-f)ile`

---

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```

Reescritura: agregarle `".php"` a lo que me piden ( descartando el slash al final si hubiere ), no tener en cuenta mayusculas `[NC]` no-case y dejar de procesar otras reglas `[L]` last

---

Todo Junto:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```