# htaccess con href del header no funciona

Tags: php, .htaccess

estoy implementando las url amigables con htaccess para quitar el .php de los links, me reconoce todas las redirecciones si las inserto manualmente en el buscador "ej: miweb/inicio, miweb/contacto".

El problema es que el href no funciona con los links de mi header, al momento de clickear en inicio del header me redirige a index.php, y así con el resto de elementos.

les comparto mi codigo de htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php


#intentando quitar el .php de las redirecciones (no funciona)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ $1/$2.php

#quitando el .php y cambiando el nombre (funciona sólo manualmente)
RewriteRule ^inicio$ index.php
RewriteRule ^contacto$ /pages/contacto.php
RewriteRule ^tarifas$ /pages/prices-2.php
```

He intentado cambiando los nombres que tengo en el href de "index.php" a "index" pero no me reconoce el archivo.
Tambien contemplar que los demas archivos que no son el index.php los tengo adentro de una carpeta /pages/contacto.php y /pages/prices.php.

Les comparto como tengo distribuido el header

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.php">Inicio</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/pages/contacto.php">Contacto</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item precios_header"><a class="nav-link" href="/pages/prices-2.php">Precios</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Direcciones que andan segun el cógido htaccess:

```
mipagina.com/inicio - mipagina.com/index.php
mipagina.com/contacto - mipagina.com/pages/contacto.php
mipagina.com/tarifas - mipagina.com/pages/prices-2.php
```

Direcciones que no andan:

```
mipagina.com/index
mipagina.com/pages/contacto
mipagina.com/pages/prices-2
```

Comment: ¿Si tecleas la URL `/pages/contacto.php` manualmente en el navegador sí te funciona?

Comment: de ambas maneras, si tecleo /pages/contacto.php o si tecleo /contacto (definido en htaccess)

Comment: Deberías editar tu pregunta y poner el ella las URLs que sí funcionan y las que no, tanto de manera automática como a través de enlaces del encabezado. Tal y como has redactado la pregunta no queda claro.

Comment: ahi actualice la pregunta para ser un poco más especifico, gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: Ahora me queda más claro. Solo funcionan las tres últimas reglas del `.htaccess`. Hoy ya es tarde, mañana reproduciré tu problema. PD: creo que dos de las reglas que no funcionan son equivalentes porque `.` también puede incluir a `/`.

Comment: @EmilianoVelázquez He reproducido tu escenario en mi servidor local y la verdad, a mi me funciona bien mi respuesta, solo que he tenido que agregar un [END] al final para que no entrara en recursión (pero eso no es lo que pasaba a ti, será por algo de mi version de apache y php). He actualizado mi respuesta con ese cambio. No se porque a ti no te funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que has intentado usar [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/568337/263200) a tu anterior [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/568334/263200), pero en esa respuesta me basé en lo que ya tenias en tu pregunta para responderte, donde ponias esto:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
```

lo cual me dio que pensar que tus URL amigables las querías así:

```
pages/contacto/
pages/prices-2/
```

pero ahora indicas que son así:

```
pages/contacto
pages/prices-2
```

con lo cual debes modificar mis reglas por estas, pues no vas a usar la barra final:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [END]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $1/$2.php [END]
```

Prueba y si tienes algun problema lo comentas, pero no vayas abriendo preguntas sobre lo mismo cuando aún no has aclarado que pasó en la otra pregunta y si te funcionó o no.

Comment: buenas! el problema que tengo es que directamente htaccess no me reconoce las url amigables con ese código automáticamente. Es decir, si clickeo en un enlace del header que me lleva a otra parte de la página me pone en el url .php, ahora si lo hago  manualmente si me redirige a la página deseada sin el .php

Comment: Ni quitándole la barra final como he puesto en esta respuesta?   Entiendo que tu url amigable es midom/pages/contacto y quieres que vaya a midom/pages/contacto.php... donde **midom** es la url de tu sitio web, por ejemplo, `https://www.ejemplo.com/`

Comment: mmm... en el header que has puesto de ejemplo no estás usando urls amigables... empezamos mal... Si quieres usar urls amigables es porque siempre vas a usarlas así, no valen medias tintas, porque entonces los buscadores te indexaran doblemente y serás penalizado por ello, y siempre tendrás lios... O tu web es con urls amigables para todo o para nada, tu decides.

Comment: claro es lo que he intentado, el problema es que como utilizo url amigables en el header? en el caso del index.php intenté poner solamente index pero no me lo reconoce, lo mismo que el resto de enlaces, si me podrías aclarar eso te lo agradezco!

Comment: Olvídate por un momento del header y verifica si escribiendo directamente `https://www.midominio.com/index` funciona o no funciona la carga de la página.  Y lo mismo para `https://www.midominio.com/pages/contacto`.  Si eso no te funciona escribiéndolo en la URL de tu navegador entonces lo del header es secundario porque no te va a funcionar nunca.  Pero si te funciona bien entonces el problema del header puede ser otro, como no usar la barra de la raíz de la web en este enlace: `href="index"` (por si estás en una página interior), pues debería ser asi: `href="/index"`